# remove and add the list items on the one button click using custom simple adapter

Tags: android, listview

I have a footer view in the list view which contain a button "Search" ,When i click on the button "Search" i want to remove the previous data and show the new one. I am fetching the the data from the web service and showing the list using Async Task.
Currently i am unable to remove the previous data ,when i click on "Search" the data added in the same list and it shows the old and new both data.

How can i refresh the list-view. Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated.

This is my code :

```
MySimpleAdapter adapter = new MySimpleAdapter(HSLoc_tabActivity.this, data , R.layout.list_main, 
                    new String[] { "name", "distance" ,"address"}, 
                    new int[] { R.id.item_title, R.id.item_subtitle ,R.id.item_subtitle1 });
            //modeList.setAdapter(adapter);
            //adapter.clear();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

            listView.invalidate();
```

Thanks !!

Comment: What is data? ArrayList?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Clear your 'data' (String[] 0r ArrayList[])first in search button's click() and then add new information into data (String[] 0r ArrayList[]) then call adapter's notifyDataSetChanged().**

just for example:

```
 searchBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
           data.clear(); // I m assuming this is ArrayList..

     // code for getting info from web and add it to data list.   

     adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this before adding new items:

```
adapter.clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have edited your code. Do the following.

```
  MySimpleAdapter adapter = new MySimpleAdapter(HSLoc_tabActivity.this, data,
                               R.layout.list_main, 
                               new String[] { "name", "distance" ,"address"}, 
                               new int[] { R.id.item_title, R.id.item_subtitle ,R.id.item_subtitle1 });
 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
 listView.invalidateViews();
 listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```